# optimize select with SUM ... CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sql-optimization

is there any way to optimize this query:

```
select 
orders_id,
orders_products_id,
sum(CASE products_options_id WHEN 1 THEN products_options_values_id ELSE 0 END) as color,
sum(CASE products_options_id WHEN 2 THEN products_options_values_id ELSE 0 END) as talle

from 
orders_products_attributes 

group by 
orders_products_id
```

This is the EXPLAIN output:

```
id  select_type   table                       type   possible_keys   key   key_len   ref     rows   Extra
1   SIMPLE        orders_products_attributes  ALL    NULL            NULL  NULL      NULL  69006  Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Thanks!

Luciano

Comment: Can you provide the EXPLAIN output and give details on what, if any, indexes you have on the table?

Comment: this is the explain output: 
id
select_type
table
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
Extra
1
SIMPLE
orders_products_attributes
ALL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
69006
Using temporary; Using filesort. Also, there there three indexes on this table: 1) on orders_products_attributes_id, 2) on orders_id, 3) on products_options_id. Thanks!

Comment: An index on orders_products_id should speed this up. Are there many values for products_options_id other than 1 and 2? What percentage of rows have one of these values? How many other columns are there?

Comment: an index on orders_products_id does not make any improvement. explain throws same data.

Comment: You might want to add the EXPLAIN output to the original question post in a formatted code tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a covering index for this query, using the columns (orders_product_id, products_options_id, orders_id).

```
CREATE INDEX ix_opa_opid_poid_oid
    ON orders_products_attributes (orders_product_id, products_options_id, orders_id)
```

Comment: same explain values with this index with same cardinality value.